# How to use external libraries for AOT in angular2?

Tags: angular, amazon-s3, angular-cli

- Environment: Operating system: Ubuntu 16.04 , IDE: Atom
- Angular version: 2.3.1
- Browser: [ Chrome 57.0.2987.110 ]
- Language: [ TypeScript 2.1.6 | ES6 ]
- Node (for AoT issues): node --version =6.9.5

When do the scripts inside scripts tag of angular-cli.json actually get executed during AOT ?

In one of my components, I have used minified amazon s3 sdk. ('aws-sdk-2.23.0.min.js')
In JIT, my app is working fine when I use

```
declare let AWS: any;
```

But in AOT it produces following error:

```
Cannot read property 'S3' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'S3' of undefined.
```

angular-cli.json contains following:

```
{
  ... 
  "apps": [
    {
     ....
      "scripts": [
         "aws-sdk-2.23.0.min.js"
      ]      
    }
  ]
  ...
}
```

Comment: try making this entry in `angular-cli.json` file

Comment: i have edited the question and added snippet for angular-cli.json file contents.

Comment: seems like your path is not correct, try giving your path from root.

Comment: Umm.. it's working on JIT though.